# CSS3 columns with one smaller

Tags: html, css

I want to separate my page into a few columns. Actually I need only three but I may need a few more later.

So I used this:

```
<style>
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;

    /*for demo purposes only */
    background: #f2f2f2;
    /*border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.column-one {
    order: 1;
}
.column-two {
    order: 2;
}
.column-three {
    order: 3;
}
</style>
```

So my page is perfectly separated in three distinct and equal columns. But I want the second smaller than the others (50%).

I already tried to reduce the width of `.column-two class` but it did not work.
Is it possible to do this with this king of code ?

I really like this structure because if I have to add one more column I do not have to change the whole CSS. That is why I want to keep this code.

Comment: can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: do u want like http://dabblet.com/gist/2700941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
       .container {
            display: flex;
            min-height: 200px;
        }

        .column {
            background: #f2f2f2;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin: 3px;
        }

        .column-one {
            flex: 1;
        }
        .column-two {
            flex: 0.5;
        }
        .column-three {
            flex: 1;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
          <div class="column column-one"></div>
          <div class="column column-two"></div>
          <div class="column column-three"></div>
 </div>
```

If You want to use four column later then.

```
                .column-one {
                    flex: 1;
                }
                .column-two {
                    flex: 0.5;
                }
                .column-three {
                    flex: 0.5;
                }
                .column-four {
                    flex: 1;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `flex: 1` to column-two and `flex: 2` to other two columns, column-two will be half width or `50%` width of other two column. Also you don't need to use order if you are not going to change it.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.column {
    /*for demo purposes only */
    background: #f2f2f2;
    /*border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.column-one {
    flex: 2;
}
.column-two {
    flex: 1;
}
.column-three {
    flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column-one"></div>
  <div class="column column-two"></div>
  <div class="column column-three"></div>
</div>
```